# Erro ao tentar da um DELETE com INNER JOIN no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELETE FROM `tb_users` 
INNER JOIN `tb_marker` ON tb_users.id_users` = `tb_marker.id_users` 
WHERE `tb_users.id_users` = 12
```

**Segue abaixo o erro:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `tb_marker` on `tb_users.id_users` = `tb_marker.id_users` WHERE `tb_u' at line 1

Comment: Não entendi, se vc tem o id_users, não seria mais simples retirar o inner join e considerar somente o where como cláusula de busca?

Answer (score 12):

Você precisa especificar de qual tabela pretende excluir o registro.

No exemplo, adicionei um alias para a tabela `tb_users` e especifiquei que queria remover o registro desta tabela.

```
DELETE u.* FROM tb_users u --Para remover apenas de tb_users
INNER JOIN tb_marker m
  on u.id_users = m.id_users
WHERE tb_users.id_users = 12
```

Comment: Não sei se o meu mysql está com algum problema, mas ele não aceita nada entre o DELETE e o FROM. Tanto no DELETE DO jbueno quanto no lnkeliz.

Comment: @MarcosPereira Estive um pouco ocupado ontem, você já achou o problema?

Comment: gostaria de deletar tbm os registros da tb_marker.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa especificar de qual tabela quer deletar, por exemplo:

```
DELETE `tb_users` FROM `tb_users` 
INNER JOIN `tb_marker` 
  on `tb_users.id_users` = `tb_marker.id_users` 
WHERE `tb_users.id_users` = 12
```

*Se quiser deletar de ambas especifique ambas.*